# Интерфейс из двух uintptr без unsafe

Tags: golang, рефлексия

С помощью пакета `refelct` можно получить данные интерфейса: указатель на информацию о типе и указатель на данные:

```
n := 42
var iface interface{} = &n
data = reflect.ValueOf(&iface).Elem().InterfaceData()
fmt.Printf("0x%x %p\n", data[1], &n)
// Output:
// 0xc420014120 0xc420014120
```

Причём, это делается без участия пакета `unsafe`.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли из `[2]uintptr` восстановить интерфейс *без участия `unsafe`?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой операции нет, так как она фундаментально небезопасна.

- Во-первых, нет гарантии, что оба числа будут указателями. Ранние имплементации хранили короткие значения в "указателе" напрямую:

  ```
  var iface interface{} = 42
  data = reflect.ValueOf(&iface).Elem().InterfaceData()
  fmt.Printf("%d\n", data[1])
  // Go 1.3 output:
  // 42
  ```
- Во-вторых, порядок тоже формально не определён. Так что `data[0]` может быть как указателем на тип, так и указателем на значение (или самим значением).
- В-третьих, как только указатель преобразуется в `uintptr`, сборщик мусора по сути забывает об этом указателе. То есть, к моменту "восстановления" интерфейса, указатель может указывать на освобождённую либо переиспользованную память. В [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) к пакету `unsafe` чётко описаны правила и инструкции, где и как использовать `unsafe.Pointer` с `uintptr`. Про интерфейсы ни слова.